# How I can find the connect values by 2 columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 2 columns. I need to find which words connect `dt$source == "learn4` in R.

The output is a vector  `c("learn2", "learn1", "learn")`

First we have  `"learn4"` connected to `"learn2"`,then  `"learn2"` connected to `"learn1"`, then  `"learn1` connected to `"learn"`

I couldn't think any way to approach the problem. Any suggestion?

```
dt <- data.frame(source = c("learn","learn1", "disc","learn2","learn3","disc1","lb","learn4"),
                 new = c("learn","learn","disc","learn1","learn1","disc","lb","learn2"))
 dt
  source   new
1  learn  learn
2 learn1  learn
3   disc   disc
4 learn2 learn1
5 learn3 learn1
6  disc1   disc
7     lb     lb
8 learn4 learn2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another `igraph` apprach would be

```
gg <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(dt)

longest_path <- function(graph, to) { 
  x <- all_simple_paths(gg, to)
  names(x[[which.max(lengths(x))]])
}

longest_path(gg, "learn4")
# [1] "learn4" "learn2" "learn1" "learn"
```

This looks how far away you can get from the input node.

Comment: I just added another question, which related to this one, if you can help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65588318/how-i-can-find-remove-the-node-child-in-r

Answer (score 3):

How about creating a graph.

```
library(igraph)
my.graph <- graph.data.frame(dt)
plot(my.graph) #not necessary, but have a look
```

Now you can find all neighbors to a specific node with `ego`:

```
names(ego(my.graph, length(V(my.graph)), "learn4")[[1]])
[1] "learn4" "learn2" "learn1" "learn"  "learn3"
```

Note that you said your requested output did not include `learn3`, but `learn1` is connected to `learn3` on line 5.

One solution might be to include `mode = "out"` as suggested by @thelatemail in the comments:

```
names(ego(my.graph, length(V(my.graph)), "learn4", mode="out")[[1]])
[1] "learn4" "learn2" "learn1" "learn"
```

Comment: Thank you, but learn3 is not in the output, just only "learn2" "learn1" "learn"

Comment: You need to specify that you are only interested in out-going connections then, rather than any links. This is a simple change to `names(ego(my.graph, length(V(my.graph)), "learn4", mode="out")[[1]])`

Comment: @thelatemail Good idea, thanks. I added it to the answer.