# How I can remove the node child in R

Tags: r

This is relate to the question I just asked couple hours ago, here is the linkv
[How I can find the connect values by 2 columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585081/how-i-can-find-the-connect-values-by-2-columns-in-r)

Now I need to remove all child nodes in dataset. If I selected `dt$source == "learn1"`, whatever nodes under "learn1" will be gone, so the output will be like this c("learn1","learn2","learn3","learn4","learn5")

I use `igraph` from @MrFlick and @Ian Campbell suggested, but I couldn't find solution.

```
dt <- data.frame(source = c("learn","learn1", "disc","learn2","learn3","disc1","lb","learn4", "learn5"),
                 new = c("learn","learn","disc","learn1","learn1","disc","lb","learn2","learn4"))

> dt
  source    new
1  learn  learn
2 learn1  learn
3   disc   disc
4 learn2 learn1
5 learn3 learn1
6  disc1   disc
7     lb     lb
8 learn4 learn2
9 learn5 learn4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in this case you are looking for `subcomponent` to find all the reachable nodes.

```
library(igraph)
gg <- graph_from_data_frame(dt)
names(subcomponent(gg, "learn1", mode = "in"))
# [1] "learn1" "learn2" "learn3" "learn4" "learn5"
```

Comment: Thank you, I use subcomponent too but I missed mode = "in"

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option (but I think the approach `subcomponent` by [@MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65588397/12158757) is more straightforward)

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(dt)
cl <- clusters(g)$membership
names(cl)[cl == cl["learn"]]
# [1] "learn"  "learn1" "learn2" "learn3" "learn4" "learn5"
```